# Tractricoid as a pseudosphere (surface with constant negative curvature)

Tags: differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, curvature

How to motivate/calculate/prove see that the tractricoid, i.e. a tractrix rotated about its asymptote, has a constant negative curvature?

What are the hyperbolic lines on a tractricoid and how to see that there are infinitely many parallel lines?

Comment: Asymptotic lines on a tractricoid using cylindrical coords $(r, \theta,z) \quad r = \sech \,
 \theta,\, z = \theta - \tanh \theta $ Since they are on a surface of revolution they are doubly infinite in number.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry not enough knowledge here but lets do an thought experiment:

As you now the tracioid is the rotation of a tractrix around its asymptope.

So lets first do the plane bit:

If you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tractrix

you can see a picture of its evolute.

the curvature of a curve is the reciprocal of the radius of the osculating circle

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_circle

for the tractrix the centre is is the point where the normal of the tractrix meets its evolute.

Now to the tracioid:

the curvature of a surface is the product of the maximum and minimal curvature of the osculating circles at a point.

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_curvature and   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature

for a point on the tracioid I think these ocilating circles are:

- the circle around its asymtope
- the circle trough its evolute

and then just multiply them

I was not able to find the right formulas that i should use here so this is more an thought experiment

I hope somebody else can elaborate on this (or show I am wrong , and how i should have done it)

Comment: Very nice! I really like your approach. It can be easily generalized and is very intuitive

Answer (score 0):

Tangent length $a$ upto asymptote x-axis is a constant =$a$.

This property of Tractrix can be  used to derive constant Gauss curvature:

$$ \dfrac{ \sin \phi  }{r}= 1/a= \dfrac{ \cos \phi* d \phi /dl }{\sin\phi} $$

$$ \dfrac{ \sin ^2 \phi  }{r^2}= 1/a^2= \dfrac{ \cos \phi }{r}\cdot  d \phi /dl;\,  \kappa_2*\kappa_1 = -K= 1/a^2 $$

The second equality is obtained using Quotient Rule of differentiation with respect to meridian arc length l by cross multiplying last two  and dividing by $r^2.$

All asymptotic lines on the surface

$$ r/a = \sech(\theta),z/a = \theta - \tanh(\theta) $$

obtained by rotation around axis of symmetry $r=0$ and their reflections in $(r-z)$ plane constitute a set parallel lines,  parallel to each other,and also "parallel" to the axis of symmetry.

Comment: I dont understand what you last line means.

Comment: Given two points on a tractricoid, what is the equation of the "straight" line that joins them?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus. I should delete it perhaps if too vague. Let me state what thoughts I have. Beltrami, Poincare etal introduced not only the surface but new lines which are shortest and are also parallel and had to be accepted as such.Anyway it became clear that euclidean picture had to be abandoned  and ideas of parallelism underwent a radical change. The asymptotic lines satisfying Sine- Gordon as geodesic parallel lines is one viewpoint.There are two asymptotes which meet at "horizon" and rest are hyper parallels:        english.turkcebilgi.com/Hyperbolic+geometry

Comment: @LittleBrownOne A closed form equation is not available like in euclidean analytical geometry but there is a differential equation in 3-space.

Comment: @LittleBrownOne: However one can tell how an equilateral triangle can be constructed on this surface. Page 79 Non Euclidean geometry by Roberto Bonola ; Ch(R a)= Ch(R b) Ch(R c)-Sh(R b)Sh(R c)Cos(A); It gives each angle of the spikey equilateral triangle Cos(A)= Ch(R a)/(1+Ch(R a) ) equalling to 52.647 degrees.

Comment: @Narasimham: I know that there exists an expression for hyperbolic lines in the disk model. Also, I've seen a transformation from the disk to a pseudosphere. I will try to search for an answer in that direction.

Comment: In 2D disk model the geodesics are normal to the boundary circle  at infinity.